Parallelizing GET requests using PyO3
I'm trying to optimize some Python code using the PyO3 library which allows me to write custom Rust code that I can import into my Python code. In particular, I'm trying to parallize requesting multiple urls in Rust, which I would then import into the Python code to get multiple URLs in parallel which I would then parse using BeautifulSoup. This is the Rust code which is giving me some issues.
use pyo3::prelude::*;
use tokio::runtime::Runtime;
use reqwest;
use futures::future;

// Function to fetch URLs in parallel
#[pyfunction]
fn fetch_urls(urls: Vec<String>) -> PyResult<Vec<String>> {
    let rt = Runtime::new().unwrap(); // Create a Tokio runtime
    let responses = rt.block_on(async {
        let futures = urls.into_iter().map(|url| {
            async {
                reqwest::get(&url).await.ok().and_then(|resp| Some(resp.text()))
            }
        });
        future::join_all(futures).await
    });
    Ok(responses.into_iter().filter_map(|x| x).collect())
}

// PyO3 module
#[pymodule]
fn rust_requests(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(fetch_urls, m)?)?;
    Ok(())
}

These are the errors I'm getting when I run maturin develop
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:13:63
   |
13 |                 reqwest::get(&url).await.ok().and_then(|resp| resp.text())
   |                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `Option<_>`, found future
   |
help: try wrapping the expression in `Some`
   |
13 |                 reqwest::get(&url).await.ok().and_then(|resp| Some(resp.text()))
   |                                                               +++++           +

error[E0599]: no method named `add_function` found for reference `&pyo3::types::PyModule` in the current scope
  --> src/lib.rs:24:7
   |
24 |     m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(fetch_urls, m)?)?;
   |       ^^^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `&PyModule`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `&pyo3::types::PyModule: WrapPyFunctionArg<'_, _>` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:24:20
   |
24 |     m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(fetch_urls, m)?)?;
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                    |
   |                    the trait `WrapPyFunctionArg<'_, _>` is not implemented for `&pyo3::types::PyModule`
   |                    required by a bound introduced by this call
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `WrapPyFunctionArg<'py, T>`:
             OnlyBound<T>
             pyo3::Bound<'py, pyo3::types::PyModule>
             pyo3::Borrowed<'_, 'py, pyo3::types::PyModule>
             pyo3::Python<'py>
             &pyo3::Bound<'py, pyo3::types::PyModule>
             &pyo3::Borrowed<'_, 'py, pyo3::types::PyModule>
   = note: this error originates in the macro `wrap_pyfunction` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0277]: the trait bound `&pyo3::types::PyModule: From<BoundRef<'_, '_, pyo3::types::PyModule>>` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:22:1
   |
22 | #[pymodule]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<BoundRef<'_, '_, pyo3::types::PyModule>>` is not implemented for `&pyo3::types::PyModule`, which is required by `BoundRef<'_, '_, pyo3::types::PyModule>: Into<_>`
   |
   = note: required for `BoundRef<'_, '_, pyo3::types::PyModule>` to implement `Into<&pyo3::types::PyModule>`
   = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `pymodule` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0277, E0308, E0599.

I'm not sure how to fix these errors as my knowledge of Rust is limited so any help would be appreciated. Here's the accompanying Cargo.toml and Python code
[package]
name = "python-rust-interop"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
name = "rust_requests"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies]
pyo3 = { version = "0.22", features = ["extension-module"] }
tokio = { version = "1.41.0", features = ["full"] }  # Add tokio with all features
reqwest = { version = "0.11", features = ["json"] }  # Add reqwest with JSON support
futures = "0.3"

from rust_requests import fetch_urls
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# List of URLs to scrape
urls = ["http://example.com", "http://example.org"]

# Fetch data using Rust
html_responses = fetch_urls(urls)

# Parse each response with BeautifulSoup
for html in html_responses:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    print(soup.title.text)


Why don't you parallelize the queries using standard python packages?

@СергейКох Because this method allows me greater speed than if it was just wholly written in Python and the tasks I'm using it for prioritize speed above all else.

This way you can increase the speed of requests, but not responses.

resp.text() is async, which means it returns a future when called (and not awaited), so Option::and_then() doesn't recognize it as returning Option. You can unpack reqwest::get(&url).await.ok().and_then(|resp| Some(resp.text())) to something like if let Ok(resp) = reqwest::get(&url).await { resp.text().await.ok() } else { None }.
